# How do I do an IF statement in my functions.php to determine if I am on the singles product page? (woocommerce)

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

Hi have made a php function that uploads script to pages with "cart" `is_cart()` and it all seems to be working properly. But when I try to use `is_product()` it doesn't register it on the single product page. How do I get my php to render script on the single product page?

I call this function in my functions.php

```
function refresh_update_qty() {
    if (is_cart() || is_product()):
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            jQuery('div.woocommerce').on('click', ' button.plus, button.minus', function(e){
                var math_method = '';
                if(jQuery(this).hasClass('plus')) {
                    math_method = "1";
                }else if(jQuery(this).hasClass('plus')) {
                    math_method = "-1";
                } else {
                //    Do nothing
                }
                var this_input = this.parentNode.querySelector('input[type=number]');
                var current_val = this_input.value;
                var new_val = parseInt(current_val) + parseInt(math_method);
                this_input.value = new_val;
                document.getElementById('update_cart_button').disabled = false;
                <?php
                if(is_cart()):
                ?>
                jQuery("[name='update_cart']").trigger("click");
                <?php
                endif;
                ?>
                e.preventDefault();
            });

        </script>
        <?php
    endif;
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'refresh_update_qty' );
```

Based on woocommerce documentation the is_product() should work, but it doesn't. https://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/is_product/

Comment: `is_product()` still works, so the problem lies elsewhere. Perhaps it can be useful to tell what your code should do or what its purpose is. By the way, you can test in a simple way whether `is_cart()`, `is_product()` or something similar works, by debugging: `if ( is_product() ) { echo 'It works'; } else { echo 'NOT working'; }`

Comment: @7uc1f3r so I tested the echo, and it worked, but when I I looked for the script I had added it did not. But I have found a solution, but is quite messy because of the redundancy of the code. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. It seems like my products page had the woocommerce class inside the body and my cart has it inside a div. so once I changed `jQuery('div.woocommerce')` to `jQuery('.woocommerce')` it worked.

Final code below

```
function refresh_update_qty() {
    if (is_cart() || is_product()):
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            (function($) {

            $('.woocommerce').on('click', ' button.plus, button.minus', function(e){
                var math_method = '';
                if($(this).hasClass('plus')) {
                    math_method = "1";
                }else if($(this).hasClass('minus')) {
                    math_method = "-1";
                } else {
                //    Do nothing
                }
                var this_input = this.parentNode.querySelector('input[type=number]');
                var current_val = this_input.value;
                var new_val = parseInt(current_val) + parseInt(math_method);
                this_input.value = new_val;
                <?php
                if(is_cart()):
                ?>
//                IF CART PAGE UPDATE CART
                document.getElementById('update_cart_button').disabled = false;
                $("[name='update_cart']").trigger("click");
                <?php
                endif;
                ?>
                e.preventDefault();
            });
            })( jQuery );

        </script>
        <?php
    endif;
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'refresh_update_qty' );
```